# Print all combinations of list that sum to a number

Tags: python

Given a list like `N = [10,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]` and `PooledMoney=23`

I need to print all lists like given below

```
[10,7,6]
[10,7,5,1]
[10,7,3,2,1]
[10,6,5,2]
[7,6,5,3,2]
```

This is my attempt:

```
for L in range(0,len(N)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(N,L):
        #print subset
        for i in subset:
            sum = sum + i
        if(sum==PooledMoney):
            print subset`
```

This doesn't print the correct subsets.

Comment: OK! What's your question?

Comment: I've updated the question with my attempt

Comment: It´s a *divide and conquer* problem: take 1st item (10) or leave it, and solve two corresponding *lesser problems*

Comment: So what does your attempt *do*, and what should it do instead? One obvious problem is that you don't seem to be resetting `sum` anywhere.

Comment: ask something. If you are asking for logic, try googling first. It is one of the most standard questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close:

```
import itertools

l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
ts = 8

def psl(l, ts):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        for c in itertools.combinations(l, i):
            if sum(c) == ts:
                print list(c)

psl(l, ts)
```